# gdb opaque symbol resolution turned off

Tags: debugging, gdb, compiler-optimization, debug-symbols

When inter-procedural-analysis optimization (compiler flag) is enabled, the struct debug symbols (opaque-symbol-resolution) does not work. Any one knows why? Is it possible to have this optimization enabled but not lose this convenient debug capability?

```
typedef struct mystruct {
  int a;
  char b;
} mystruct_t;
```

Without ipa enabled,

```
(gdb) p /x global_var
$1 = {a = 0xdeadbeef, b = 0xa}
```

With ipa enabled,

```
(gdb) p /x global_var
$1 = 0xdeadbeef
```

Comment: Is the `b` field actually used? The compiler may have  created a specialized version of `mystruct` that is  just an `int`.

Comment: Yes it is used. The issue is about debug symbols getting stripped out with ipa compiler flag.